# strange behavior with CSS transition on Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari, css-transitions

I have a div which gets the width set to 280px:

HTML:

```
<div id="propertiesPane">.. </div>
```

CSS:

```
#propertiesPane {
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: auto !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: width 0.1s linear;
    transition: width 0.1s linear;
}

#propertiesPane.collapsed {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Also, what's happening is in JavaScript code, on document ready and depending on a flag, the 'collapsed' class is applied, which sets the width to 50px.

The problem is this works fine on desktop (IE, FF, Chrome) and Android 4.3 but not on Safari iOS 8+.

On Safari, although the 'collapsed' class gets applied, the width is not 50px but 280px. If I remove the 'transition' line from the CSS id selector, it works OK.

Is there a strange "race condition"-like on applying the width on Safari? I'm inclined it is, because sometimes I see it works correctly, the width is set to 50px.

**JSFiddle**: **https://jsfiddle.net/fkhq88eb/3/**

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your issue on Safari 8.0.8 – maybe you have performance issues? Try to use transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to involve GPU in rendering of this block.

Comment: @LaFaulx thanks! funny, it looks like the JsFiddle example is working for me too but not the actual app. I obviously can't show all the code of my app, so wonder what's breaking it there

Comment: @LaFaulx in a real app, can't it be a race condition on the setting width from the transition in CSS and from Javascript?

Comment: I don't think so – you set collapsed class and only after that transition is applied.

Comment: I added 'transform: translate3d(0,0,0)' after 'transition: width 0.1s linear;' and still won't work

Comment: something very strange is going on. In the timeline, I see a lot of "Styles Recalculated" followed by "Styles Invalidated". If I keep recording on, I see these are generated non-stop. I guess something is changing continuously the layout, but I can't see what is it.

Comment: strange, if I remove the 'transform' everything works fine

Comment: I can't find a good way to debug this, any recommendations?